# What is the purpose of Local Listener in Oracle 11gR2 RAC?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-rac

I have 3 node 11gR2 RAC database setup. I stopped the local listener (e.g.LAB_LISTENER) on all nodes, however I am able to to connect to the database using sqldeveloper tool. As far as I understand, in 11gR2, SCAN Listener redirects the user connection request to local listener and then local listener establish the connection between client and the database.

What is the purpose of Local Listener in Oracle 11gR2 RAC?

```
[oracle@oradbrac1 ~]$ ps -ef|grep tns
root        15     2  0 Feb04 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
oracle   13741     1  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /u01/app/oracle/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr LAB_LISTENER -inherit
grid     13763     1  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /u01/app/grid11204/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
grid     13984     1  0 10:32 ?        00:00:00 /u01/app/grid11204/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER_SCAN3 -inherit
```

Please advise.

Thank you,
SA

Comment: The purpose of the local listener is to spawn server process(id dedicated server mode) or to handover your request to the dispatcher(in shared-server mode) in order to process your requests.

Comment: In that case can you shade some light on how users can connect to the database even when local listeners are down on all nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this LAB_LISTENER running on oracle home and its not part of cluster resource. Stopping these wont affect any connections to cluster database.

Could you please share us the local_listener parameter settings from database all 3 instances.

Thanks.